# How to add all the values in the column and display the added values in the table footer

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am using iTextsharp for generating pdf report. Here I am displaying all the values of the table. Here I need to add all the values in the particular column and display that total value in the footer.

In the below code I need to add all the values from the Hours spent column and display the value in the newly added row. Anyone help me to sort out this

```
 public byte[] Report(DataTable dtReport, string reportType, string headerName, int businessId, int mode, string CultureInfo)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn col in dtReport.Columns)
                col.ColumnName = resourceDictionary[colKey];
        foreach (DataRow row in dtReport.Rows)
        {
            if ((dtReport.Columns.Contains("Hours Spent")))
                row["Status"] += row["Hours Spent"].ToString();
        }

        switch (reportType)
        {
            case "PDF":
                return ExportDataTableToPdf(dtReport headerName, mode);
            case "XLSX":
                return ExportDataTableToExcel(dtReport, true);
            case "DOCX":
                return ExportDataTableToWord(dtReport);
            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: *"add all the values from the Hours spent column"* - you are aware that in your code you use string concatenation, not numeric addition, aren't you? I doubt the result is what you expect. That being said, you say you want help but you don't say what exactly you need help for. What part of your code has a result differing from your expectations? Or what part of your assignment do you not know how to handle?